# How to read or parse remote csv(On Google Drive) GAE(Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

I have csv files on google drive and they public , i must read this csv`s in GAE with Python.

My Solution is

```
def get_content(self, id):
        file = self.get_item(id)
        if file['downloadUrl'] is not None:
            url = file.get('downloadUrl')
            content = self.service._http.request(url)
            return content
        else:
            return None
```

but i don`t parse this content , any ideas ???

Comment: look at python standard csv parser.  It's in the docs.

Comment: I know python standart parser , but here GAE in the docs i set csv absolute path for csv reader , but GAE i don`t set absolute path , so my csv file in google drive ... i have google drive file stream read stream ...

Comment: You don't need to use a path.  Wrap the result from the http request in a StringIO instance, and then pass that to the csv reader.  You should read the docs more carefully for csv reader.  http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html  - it says - *Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile. csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its next() method is called — file objects and list objects are both suitable. *

Comment: sorry i don`t understand you , please show me any examples with code. there are csv file must be on google drive.

Answer (score 1):

Its really straight forward.  I suggest you spend some time reading up on what StringIO does and how it is used, you may find you will be using a bit.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import csv


content = StringIO(content)
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(content))
```

You will use the same mechanism if you need to write csv files.

Comment: Yes it does.  Once you have fetched the csv file from drive you can use the csv parser and stringio.  In what way can't you do it ?

Comment: I haven't shown you everything.  Just how to package a string in a file like construct so you can parse it. I assumed you can read the docs and work the rest out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getService(self):
    http = httplib2.Http()
    scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    cred = build_credentials(scope=scope)
    cred.authorize(http)
    service = build("drive", "v2", http=http)
    return service

def getFileFromDrive(self):
    service = self.getService()
    myfile = service.files().get(fileId="myfileId").execute()
    url = myfile['downloadUrl']
    content = service._http.request(url)
    return content

def fileOpeation(self):
    content = self.getFileFromDrive()
    StringIO(content)
    reader = csv.reader(StringIO(content))
    return reader
```

Here my finally code , that is worked  ! Thank you Tim